# Oracle SQL Connect By Level - literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I want to generate dates between 2 dates coming from parameters in oracle fusion using the `connect by level` statement

```
SELECT   papf.person_number emp_id,
(SELECT to_date(:p_from_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') + level - 1 dt
from   dual
connect by level <= (
  to_date(:p_to_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') - to_date(:p_from_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') + 1
) ),
....
```

I get error `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`, I tried to use `to_char` and change the format but doesn't work, the parameter date format is also `dd-mm-yyyy`, what is wrong here?

Comment: Row generator subquery is OK, it works just fine if parameters do follow format model you specified. Are you sure that it (and not some other part of query) returns that error?

Comment: yeah, when i remove this part it works fine

Comment: Pass dates as dates, not as strings. Then you will not need `to_date`

Comment: parameters would be something like this : P_TO_DATE (2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00) P_FROM_DATE (2021-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00), they are already dates, i use to_date to format them, i can use to_char to or i can even use the parameters as is, but nothing works

Comment: if i use ```to_char``` it says ```invalid number```, if i use parameters as is it says ```invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT   
    dt --papf.person_number emp_id
FROM
    (
        SELECT to_date(:p_from_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') + level - 1 dt
        FROM   dual
        connect by level <= to_date(:p_to_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') - to_date(:p_from_date,'dd-mm-yyyy') + 1) papf
```

Your inner query selects just the dt column, FROM was missing, brackets in wrong places... Anyway with variables bound as 01-01-2023 and 10-01-2023 the result is:

```sql
dt
----------
01-JAN-23
02-JAN-23
03-JAN-23
04-JAN-23
05-JAN-23
06-JAN-23
07-JAN-23
08-JAN-23
09-JAN-23
10-JAN-23
```

If your parameters are of DATE data type then

```sql
SELECT   
    To_Char(dt, 'dd-mm-yyyy') "DT"
FROM
    (
        SELECT :p_from_date + level - 1 dt
        FROM   dual
        connect by level <= :p_to_date - :p_from_date + 1) papf  

DT
----------
01-01-2023
02-01-2023
03-01-2023
04-01-2023
05-01-2023
06-01-2023
07-01-2023
08-01-2023
09-01-2023
10-01-2023
```

Comment: i used it as separate query, doesn't work, same error

Comment: Can you catch the values that you are getting to be bound? This error is usualy missmatch of string with the specified format. Even quotes could cause the problem.

Comment: parameters would be something like this : ```P_TO_DATE (2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00)
P_FROM_DATE (2021-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00)```, they are already dates, i use ```to_date``` to format them, i can use ```to_char``` to or i can even use the parameters as is, but nothing works

Comment: You don't need anything to generate  the dates. Just if you are selecting the date and want it shown in a particular format other than the one already set with NLS vars then you do To_Char to do the format you want. So, if you are gettingg  dates then don't use to_date.

Comment: if i use to_char it says invalid number, if i use parameters as is it says invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic

Comment: Just put it like this :p_to_date - :p_from_date + 1 within connect by clause

Comment: and in select clause :p_from_date + level - 1

Comment: DATE - DATE is number (of days)   --> and DATE + 1 is DATE (of next day)

Comment: Just posted an addition for date params

Comment: it worked using ```trunc``` for parameters

Comment: Great. Good job.